# TeamCity The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: shell, maven, teamcity, artifactory

I was trying to run a customer script on TeamCity. This script is to rename a release tar file previous release to artifactory local directory. Remove the snapshot and date in the name of tar file:

```
ren %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\target\project-%maven.project.version%-pkg.tar.gz project-%maven.project.version%-%build.counter%-pkg.tar.gz
ren %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\target\project-%maven.project.version%-pkg.zip project-%maven.project.version%-%build.counter%-pkg.zip
```

For example, I have a tar file named `project-3.0.18-20170324.190100-1.pom`, i want to rename it to `project-8.0.18.pom`.

The problem i got now is :

```
Step 2/2: rename snapshot (Command Line)
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script193311797169104291.cmd
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\46536700c4bd208f
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] The system cannot find the file specified.
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] The system cannot find the file specified.
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
[09:59:08][Step 2/2] Step rename snapshot (Command Line) failed
```

I am not sure what exactly is the problem. why teamcity is looking for the command line in  C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script193311797169104291.cmd.
And why it can not find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `custom_script193311797169104291.cmd` - a temporary generated file with script you want to execute.

just add some `echo` commands into your command script to see if it works.

```
echo workdir=%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%
echo version=%maven.project.version%
echo %teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\target\project-%maven.project.version%-pkg.tar.gz
```

and check that source file exists...

actually the `ren` command reports that file not found.

nothing about scriptname

Comment: Thanks, Let me try that.